Is it not smart to answer old questions?
I randomly found some questions I thought very interesting or probably I would have asked during my school time. However, you will see that no one even tried to answer it at all although been tagged several times.
When I spent a lot of time in writing such answers, I often felt hesitant since it might be lost in the thread ocean and the most posssible is that the OP might even forgot or completely didn't need the answer at all.
Would you please kindly give any advice?

By answering, it brings the question to the top of the active section. Other users may find the answer useful.

Ok, good! This is the value.

Why any individual answers a question is really up to them. It might be to be helpful to the asker, which would make it less useful to answer old questions. It might be just because you want to add an answer for posterity, so future searches might find your answer.  If you are wanting attention, answering old questions is less rewarding. (You should make sure your answer isn't already there, which makes old questions a little more work, depending on how many answers are there already.)

For such questions usually it's best to ask them in the Meta forum: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com
But to answer your question, you should still go ahead and answer them (provided no duplicate answers have come up since), because there may always be someone else (not necessarily OP) who has the same question as OP, and finds your answer helpful!

I just couldn't understand that some questions which are obviously valuable, but not even received any comments. Take this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1144564 for example. I could remember that many years ago, I spent a lot of days studing this Jacobian and implicite differential equations whileas I didn't realize this can be asked here.

Don't answer questions that are not math questions here. Questions about the site should go to the corresponding Meta site. This would have been fine as a comment.

@Thomas Andrews, I might have not really understood the rules. I didn't know if it is proper to ask. Shall I remove the question then?
